# Wysija Newsletters: Redirect After Subcription

Tags: plugins

I am using [Wysija Newsletters plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wysija-newsletters/). After I click button "Subscribe", I want to be redirected to custom page. How to do I this? Can you can do this?

This is my page: http://cheapproducts4you.com/index.html

Comment: I don't know that plugin, so where do you want to have this feature? Is the _Subscribe_ link in the widget? Is it generated by a short-code? Is it placed inside the newsletter/e-mail? We need more context here...

Comment: Hi, I want to have this feature in html page.

Answer (score -1):

You can. Read this here:

http://support.wysija.com/knowledgebase/customize-your-confirmation-pages/

Thank you.

Comment: Link only answers are considered poor quality. Please add some code and explain why this helps. Thanks.